# improving loading performance by hosting images on different server

Tags: html, css, image, wordpress, seo

If you're hosting a blog on a shared server and you're concerned about page loading time, would it at least theoretically be better to host the images in an Amazon S3 bucket and then just link to them?

As Google apparently takes page loading into consideration, will this possibly improve search rankings?

Comment: Try asking on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about search rankings but it really improves your page load speed. It commonly known as CDN. You can use this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/ and it has an option to select a cdn that includes the amazon server. So managing images between your wordpress and the amazon server is pretty easy by using this plugin. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes Good Idea. It will improve your web site performance by moving your media files from your main web server. This could be as simple as creating a sub-domain that points to a host that serves your media files.

Amazon S3  also provides a simple web services interface that can be used to store and retrieve any amount of data, at any time, from anywhere on the web.

Generally, software developers use `Amazon S3` in their applications that need the same highly scalable, reliable, fast, inexpensive data storage infrastructure that Amazon uses to run its own global network of web sites